# "File tikz.sty not found" error after updating MiKTeX 2.9

Tags: tikz-pgf, miktex2.9, miktex-update

After the update today I get the error message: File `tikz.sty' not found. There must be a problem with the latest version of MiKTeX 2.9.

Comment: See https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/80. The MikTeX developer knows about this and the issue should be fixed in tomorrow's update. If you can't wait that long you have to get `pgf.tds.zip` from CTAN and install that.

Comment: Please search for duplicate questions before posting a new one (we had this question three times in the last 2 hours). Also please report package or distribution errors always directly to the developer over its support contact channel (website, forum, whatever they have for this). Stackexchange is not a bug tracker.