# Using TikZ package in TexStudio

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, packages

Im trying to use the package TikZ by inserting `\usepackage{TikZ}` into my preamble on TexStudio however it keeps coming up with the error that TikZ.sty is not found.  I have MiKTeX and have checked the console to see that it is allowing for missing packages although i am not sure what link should be in the gap for where the packages are downloaded?

Does anyone know why my TikZ package would not be working?

Thanks

Comment: in the recent `miktex` the `tikz` is broaken. we should wait for new `miktex` version ...

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/468976/87876

Comment: @Zarko Did you *read* the question?

Comment: @marmoth, did i miss read it? if i did, than i apologies to all for any inconvenience (i'm still under impression that `tikz` doesn't work in  recent `miktex`).

Comment: @Zarko That's all true but there is the issue described in [Alan's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/469074/121799).

Comment: I voted to mark this as duplicate of the other question because I think from the fact that this question is about miktex makes it very likely that also windows is involved in which case the capitalization would not be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

TeX is case sensitive. The package name is `tikz` when called not `TikZ`.  So you should use

```
\usepackage{tikz}
```

If you are doing this (and not using `\usepackage{TikZ}` as you wrote in your question) then the problem is a transient problem with MikTeX which should be fixed in a day or so as noted in the comments.

This issue has nothing to do with your editor.

Comment: On Windows the file system is not case sensitive, so `tikz.sty` and `TikZ.sty` are the same. Hence `kpathsea` will find `tikz.sty` even if one types `TikZ`. One does get a warning ```LaTeX Warning: You have requested package `TikZ', but the package provides `tikz'.``` though, because as you say *TeX* is case sensitive.